# Processing time difference between tuple-list

Tags: python, list, time, tuples, python-3.4

Wondering why this tuple process;

```
x = tuple((t for t in range(100000)))
# 0.014001131057739258 seconds
```

Took longer than this list;

```
y = [z for z in range(100000)]
# 0.005000114440917969 seconds
```

I learned that `tuple` processes are faster than `list` since tuples are immutable.

Edit: After I changed the codes;

```
x = tuple(t for t in range(100000))
y = list(z for z in range(100000))
>>> 
0.009999990463256836
0.0
>>>
```

These are the result: Still tuple is the slower one.

Comment: try timing `x = list(t for t in range(100000))`, your first example you are calling tuple on a generator expression so they are not doing the same job

Comment: And `x = tuple(t for t in range(100000))`

Comment: But isn't that may a list then?

Comment: @alana, it is a list

Comment: But I want that x as a tuple and y as a list

Comment: is there a reason not to use `tuple(range(10**5))` and `list(range(10**5))`?

Answer (score 1):

Tuple operations aren't necessarily faster. Being immutable at most opens the door to more optimisations, but that doesn't mean Python does them or that they apply in every case.

The difference here is very marginal, and - without profiling to confirm - it seems likely that it relates to the generator version having an extra name lookup and function call. As mentioned in the comments, rewriting the list comprehension as a call to `list` wrapped around a generator expression, the difference will likely shrink.

Answer (score 0):

using comparative methods of testing the tuple is slightly faster:

```
In [12]: timeit  tuple(t for t in range(100000))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.41 ms per loop

In [13]: timeit list(t for t in range(100000))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.53 ms per loop
```

calling list does actually create a list:

```
In [19]: x = list(t for t in range(10))

In [20]: x
Out[20]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

we can also see calling list on the generator does not allocate as much space as using a list comprehension:

```
In [28]: x = list(t for t in range(10))

In [29]: sys.getsizeof(x)
Out[29]: 168

In [30]: x = [t for t in range(10)]

In [31]: sys.getsizeof(x)
Out[31]: 200
```

So both operations are very similar.

A better comparison would be creating lists and tuples as subelements:

```
In [41]: timeit tuple((t,) for t in range(1000000))
10 loops, best of 3: 151 ms per loop

In [42]: timeit list([t] for t in range(1000000))
1 loops, best of 3: 247 ms per loop
```

Now we see  a much larger difference.

Comment: `tuple(range(10**5))` is slightly slower than `list(range(10**5))` on my machine: `3.2` vs. `3.06` ms

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, well it is slightly faster on mine, there is very little difference either way as I pointed out in my answer, the real way to compare is using the last example.